# Why does the reactive form sample pass data to onvalueChanged but not use it

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am just learning ng2 reactive forms with the official sample:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#live-example

Have a look at the defined method:  onValueChanged(data?: any) {

where data might be passed, but it is never used within the method?

Why then subscribe to it some lines above ? =>

```
  this.heroForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
```

Can anyone explain me please this odd code?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': [this.hero.name, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.maxLength(24),
          forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)
        ]
      ],
      'alterEgo': [this.hero.alterEgo],
      'power':    [this.hero.power, Validators.required]
    });

    this.heroForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now
  }


  onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.heroForm) { return; }
    const form = this.heroForm;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  formErrors = {
    'name': '',
    'power': ''
  };

  validationMessages = {
    'name': {
      'required':      'Name is required.XXX',
      'minlength':     'Name must be at least 4 characters long.',
      'maxlength':     'Name cannot be more than 24 characters long.',
      'forbiddenName': 'Someone named "Bob" cannot be a hero.'
    },
    'power': {
      'required': 'Power is required.'
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thats boring... someone wants to close this reasonable question without reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the author wanted to show that you can subscribe to the data to use it, but it's not a fully fleshed out example.

Don't worry about the data variable not being used in this case, it's just an example. There is no additional meaning behind it and there are no side effects elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When - this.rentApartmentForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data)); is removed, the code sample no longer finds and displays the validationMessages. A validation error is recognized, but no message appears.  Typescript errors say 'data' has to be in both expressions to match things up.

But there is an error in this code sample.  In the expression further down, - for (const key in control.errors), Typescript says "control.errors may be null".

When this expression is in the code, the page will not load (using Angular 4.4.3) Some console error about 'possibly null' appears. When commented out, the page will load, but not show validationMessages. In a development environment, the line can be added back in, everything works, no Console error appears, and validationMessages appear for the user.

Something is messed up. Anyone know what change needs to be made?